# Navigating to a html page from Windows Application

Tags: windows-ce, windows-mobile-5.0, compact-framework2.0

I have to create an native application for the device which has Windows CE 5.0 and having .NET CF 2.0 installed in it. The App has to get the ip address of the device and then open an html page to which the ip address has to be passed by using POST method.

I am able to get the ip address and open the page using process.start. But this is using GET method(i can see the value in the address bar)

Now how can i POST the parameter to the page??

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 pro edition.

Please Help....Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my blo article here: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2009/06/14/mdiwatch2/

It shows how to use POST to send data to a server (java servlet). The code uses HttpWebRequest and then builds the POST stream.

In a simpler form you just need to use HttpWebRequest and the just build your special URI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The Link was helpful. I am able to POST data using HttpWebRequest.